# powershell wildcard matching/regex

Tags: regex, powershell, wildcard

I have the following code below I have to get down to under 260 characters.
I had another post like this before and a powershell wizard came through and introduced me to wildcard matching, and although I spent hours studying what he did I can not figure out how to replicate the dark magic. Would someone be so kind to inform me. I have scoured the internet for reference and have failed on that front as well.

```
(netsh wlan show profiles) | sls "\:(.+)$" | %{$n=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{(netsh wlan show profile name="$n" key=clear)}  | sls "Key Content\W+\:(.+)$" | %{$p=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{[PSCustomObject]@{ ssid=$n;pass=$p }}
```

This is the example the wizard showed me. My code above this needs to use the same technique to shorten it even further.

this:
`Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms`

to:

`Add-Type -AssemblyName *m.W*s.F*s`

Comment: The first example shows RegEx, not wildcard expression.

Comment: ok well no matter how hard I try to replicate what he did with other commands it never works

Comment: Probably because most cmdlets don't accept either RegEx, or Wildcard Patterns. So, your question is just trying to shorten `System.Windows.Forms` using RegEx/Wildcard Patterns?

Comment: no that is an exmaple of how it was shown to me working, I need to apply that to the code above it

Comment: Your first example is just using a bunch of default aliases.  Run `Get-Alias` command and you can see what is defined by default.  If you want to add your own you can use `New-Alias`.  To see other commands dealing with aliases you can run `gcm *alias` (`gcm` being an alias for `Get-Command` which you could learn by doing `Get-Alias gcm`)

Comment: there is no first example. The first snippet of code is what needs to be shortened more even with all the alias i used. Which i used them all. The code still needs to be shorter hence using the wild card matching used in the FIRST and only example with the "Add-Type" code

Comment: hopefully it was just edited for clarity enough to explain my objective.

Comment: This is 216 characters `switch -r(netsh wlan show profiles){'\:(.+)$'{$n = $Matches[1].Trim();switch -r(netsh wlan show profile name="$n" key=clear){'Key Content\W+\:(.+)$'{$p = $Matches[1].Trim();[PSCustomObject]@{ssid = $n; pass = $p}}}}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically what you're doing is [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). It's ugly and not something that is usually recommended. If I recall correctly, for some reason you're trying to fit scripts like this into the Run box. This is the smallest I could get it with a decently described object at the end.

```
switch -r(netsh wl sh pr){':\s(.+)'{$s=$matches.1;switch -r(netsh wl sh pr n=$s k=clear){'tent.+:\s(.+)'{[PSCustomObject]@{SSID=$s;Pass=$matches.1}}}}}
```

Comment: Beat mine... Nice

Comment: Yes that is correct. Run box accepts 259 characters. To be clear your help is extremely appreciated but I also want to learn how to incorporate this functionality myself though it is understandably ugly. Was it trial and error for you or is there actually documentation somewhere?

Comment: @IamJakoby, it's about the art of refactoring.  The more you know about the programming/scripting language, the better, because then you can look at the code and see that it can be rewritten a different way.  For example, with the sls and match combination you had I realized that that could be done more concisely with a switch statement.  Doug here realized that he could skip the $p assignment completely and just output it in the psobject.  Also shortening the netsh parameters was genius.  I was thinking there might even be a way to define a quick function since some of the code repeats

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I am putting as much effort as I can into becoming more proficient every day and trying to learn something new. I like asking in here not because I'm lazy but the community as a whole has a level of ingenuity that's often not even in the docs and I greatly appreciate being able to learn from you guys. You just now gave me a lot to explore and I'm appreciative.

Comment: Keep it up.  Some advice.  Go through [this guy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) answers and responses and you will learn A LOT